# How to remove the final \n?

Tags: linux, command-line, python

Using a CLI command in Python `ps -au | awk '{print$1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$11}' | sed '1d'` to obtain the following output:

```
root 669 0.0 0.0 tty1 /sbin/agetty
root 670 0.4 2.8 tty7 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
lothar 1573 0.0 0.0 pts/0 sh
lothar 1599 0.0 0.0 pts/0 /bin/bash
lothar 21130 0.0 0.1 pts/1 /usr/bin/bash
lothar 21140 0.0 0.1 pts/2 /usr/bin/bash
lothar 21146 0.0 0.1 pts/3 /usr/bin/bash
lothar 21230 0.0 0.1 pts/4 /usr/bin/bash
lothar 508386 0.0 0.0 pts/0 ps
lothar 508387 0.0 0.0 pts/0 [awk]
lothar 508388 0.0 0.0 pts/0 sed
```

This set of commands however inserts an additional `\n` char. I know I can use tr in the linux cli to remove all `\n`'s, but i only need to remove the last one.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? You'd end up with the last line being no longer delimited, meaning it won't be valid text any longer, which means it won't be post-processable reliably with standard text utilities.

Comment: Do you want to have a non-terminated last line, or do you have an _empty_ line in the output that you want to remove? If you are looking for a way of removing an empty trailing line, it would be interesting to see how you call this shell pipeline and output its result from your Python code.

Comment: The `awk | sed` combo can be simplified with `awk 'NR>1 {print$1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$11}'`

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple tool designed to solve problems like this:

```
truncate -s -1
```

But better confirm that there is a trailing newline first:

```
[ -z "$(tail -c1 file)" ] && truncate -s -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just make awk not print the last newline.  Converted to printf, only print newlines before strings, except the first string.

```
ps -au | awk '{if (NR > 1) { print "" }; printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s", $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$11); }'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to do that in Bash.
For example, pipe this command:

```
head -c-1
```

to remove the last byte from the output.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Python to do this, create a .py file with below code:

```py
from pathlib import Path

contents = Path("myfile.txt").read_text(encoding="UTF-8").splitlines()
Path("myfile.txt").write_text("".join(contents), encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: ok maybe some additional clarity might help. This data never hits a file. Its placed into a TkSheets sheet for viewing within a TKinter app.

Comment: @LotharTheQuiet if you're doing all this in Python, why not use `rstrip()`? Or if you already have a list of lines, something like `lines = lines[:-1]`?

Comment: @Muru thank you for this! This was the method that I ended up using. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LotharTheQuiet do not use rstrip() to delete \n, this method used to clear all *SPACE* charatcters right of line. This means \t, \v, space will be deleted unexpectly. Just use splitlines() to cross delete \r, \n, \r\n.

Have you ever treat lines for Markdown or code commments? 2 right spaces means next line block for code, once you delete them, once you detete them, format changed

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of this "trick" solution right now. It works because you echo something without the following newline, and the something is the output from ps in this case.

```
 echo -n "$(ps -au | awk '{print$1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$11}' | sed 1d |tail -n3)NONEWLINE"
```

output:

```
balmora: ~/src/github.com/systemd/systemd
$ echo -n "$(ps -au | awk '{print$1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$11}' | sed 1d |tail -n3)NONEWLINE"
jaroslav 821201 0.0 0.0 pts/9 awk
jaroslav 821202 0.0 0.0 pts/9 sed
jaroslav 821203 0.0 0.0 pts/9 tailNONEWLINEbalmora: ~/src/github.com/systemd/systemd [main]
```